# Hartshorne Remark II.5.16.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In remark 5.16.1 the claim is made that if $i\colon X\to \mathbb{P}^r_Y$ is a closed immersion, then $i^*(\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is a very ample invertible sheaf on $X$, but I cannot determine why it is locally of rank 1. I tried to appeal directly to the definition of $i^*(\mathcal{O}(1))$, but wasn't able to make any sort of meaningful progress.

Comment: In the copy I'm looking at, he says in that remark that $i^* \mathcal O(1)$ is very ample which is purely definitional, not the sheaf you mentioned.

Comment: The pullback of the structure sheaf is the structure sheaf, which implies that the pullback of a locally free sheaf of rank $n$ is again a locally free sheaf of rank $n$. The linked duplicate tells you this.